# Can't build Ruhr valley wonder for some reason

Tags: civilization-6-gathering-storm

I had a mine left of where the Industrial district is.
I removed the mine, and expected that I would be able to build the wonder, but for some reason CIV6 still says "*no suitable location*".

Can't wonders be built where roads are, or is there something else I am missing?

[image: unbuildable]

Comment: Does the industrial district belong to Sheffield, and does it contain a factory?

Comment: @Cadence You are quite right! It turned out that while the industrial district did belong to Sheffield, the tile, where I wanted to build Ruhr valley, did NOT. Would be glad to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wonders and districts can only be built on tiles that your city owns, through natural growth or purchasing. If another city in your empire got to that tile first, you can use manual citizen assignment (the citizen head icon in the lower-right of the city overlay) in the destination city to assign a worker to that tile. This should adjust the underlying ownership of that tile and let the newly assigned city build districts and wonders there as well. (Thanks to @Michael Campbell for confirming that this works in Gathering Storm.)

In this case, the hills tile in question was originally claimed by the city of Bristol, so only Bristol can build wonders there; Sheffield cannot. However, the adjacent Industrial Zone district belongs to Sheffield, so Bristol cannot use it to meet the requirements of Ruhr Valley. (Note that the wonder tooltip explicitly requires that the industrial zone belong to the same city as is building the wonder.)

You can purchase a tile with gold if you notice that it's about to be taken by the wrong city and you want to ensure a specific city has that space for districts and wonders.

Comment: If you click on the Icon with the head in the lower right you can manage which tiles citizens are working. From here, you should have the option to "swap" ownership of tiles within your empire. This should allow you to build on them.

Comment: @MIchaelCampbell The research I did suggested that while you could change which city worked which tile, that *wouldn't* change the underlying "ownership" of them, which jibes with what I recall of Civ V using the same system. I haven't done much experimenting with it in Civ VI though.

Comment: I know that the Civ Wiki does seem to suggest that is the case, and while I can't speak to previous xpacs of Civ VI with certainty, I am certain that as of Gathering Storm this does change the underlying ownership, and does allow you to build on the swapped tile. To confirm, I just opened up a save file swapped a tile over, and was able to build a district on the swapped tile with the new city,

Comment: @MichaelCampbell Interesting, I've added that information to the answer. I appreciate your going and testing for us all.