# Panama canal not in list of wonders?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-gathering-storm

I have all the techs prior to Panama canal researched. I have civics in Industrial era, although civics are not as advanced as tech tree.

**For some reason the option to build it doesn't appear on my wonder list in cities**. Are there any hidden requirements, such as oil (which I don't have as resource, although I do have Refining researched)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's allright, turned out somebody else beat me to Panama canal.
Nevertheless I remember previous situations where just getting the Tech tree ability didn't allow me to build it, until I had, if I remember right "Chemistry".

Comment: @hammythepig It just means the OP (or someone else) can turn that comment into an answer. It doesn't invalidate the question (I'm assuming you voted to close - if not, just ignore this comment :).

Comment: @Joachim ah yes, sorry! I clicked vote to close as it seemed they already had an answer, first time doing that so sorry if I did it wrong!

Comment: @hammythepig No worries. Closing questions is only done (in case you don't yet know) when the question is off-topic, a duplicate, opinion-based, and the like (see [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)).

Comment: @hammythepig - marking questions as closed and marking questions as answered are *very* different here. I would advise against closing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has already answered own question [in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/356167/panama-canal-not-in-list-of-wonders#comment501889_356167):

> it's allright, turned out somebody else beat me to Panama canal

Someone already made the wonder, so it can't be built again.
Just posting here so the question can be answered.

Comment: Possibly also useful to link other question (I am afraid, also by me) where it turned out the city didn't have (that particular hex) under control to build the wonder: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349298/cant-build-ruhr-valley-wonder-for-some-reason